# Meteor - alter data on publish

Tags: mongodb, security, meteor, publish, playing-cards

I am doing a card game in Meteor. Each played game is registered in the collection "Games".
A Games' record contain some of the game info as well as some players info and the cards hand of the players (`players[i].cards`, with values like `4S` - 4 of spade, `KH` - king of heart...). Depending on the cards value, I can display the correct card to the frontend (`div.card-KH`).

Most of the game data is public but, of course, only the current player's cards must be visible.

One option could be to exclude the cards of the other players at publish time but I still need the number of cards to display the decks (only the remaining cards, hidden) of the other players.

Is there a way to replace the card value of each cards (except user's ones) in `players[i].cards` to, say, `BACK` *(`div.card-BACK`)* at publish time? Else, what would be the good design pattern to do this in Meteor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the only solution I found (I don't really like it but it works) :

Basically, you have to store a temporary document, with the same id but modified data, to another Collection, publish that document from that Collection and finally, from client side, subscribe to that publication.
Of course, never make hidden part of the original document available through another publication.

```js
Meteor.publish('gameWithHiddenCards', function (gameId) {
    var self = this;

    //Transform function
    var transform = function(item) {
        for (var i=0; i<item.players.length; i++){
            if ((item.players[i].id != self.userId))
                for (var j = 0; j < item.players[i].cards.length; j++)
                    item.players[i].cards[j] = 'back';
        return item;
    };

    /* 1. Observe changes in game ;
       2. Apply transform function on game data ;
       3. Store it to another Collection. */
    var observer = Games.find({_id: gameId}).observe({
        added: function (document) {
            self.added('secure_games', document._id, transform(document));
        },
        changed: function (newDocument, oldDocument) {
            self.changed('secure_games', newDocument._id, transform(newDocument));
        },
        removed: function (oldDocument) {
            self.removed('secure_games', oldDocument._id);
        }
    });

    self.onStop(function () {
        observer.stop();
    });

    // Return altered game
    return SecureGames.find({_id: gameId});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer. You could make it a bit faster by item.players[i].cards=item.players[i].cards.length so that it would just be a number for the other players cards (they are all blank)
(If player has the same number of cards it could just be item.players[i].cards=null)
OR add 1 (2 if noOfCards is different) fields: item.cards[i] (item.noOfCards[i]) which would be the cards belonging to player i and in the publication of the public information do: .find({}, {fields: {cards: 0}});

Comment: Well, the way I code it allow me to change nothing on the template (simply use another card if the css class is `card-back`).
Your way would indeed ba a bit faster (altough we are talking about max 13*3 = almost nothing for a cpu... ok, he has to deal with all current playing game, each time a card is played) but it is more complicated on the template (you have to check if cards is a number and that case create a template helper to fill the deck). I prefer to keep it simple to debug.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question which I think there should be an official guideline to.

They have a bit in the docs about publishing:
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish (secretinfo field only published to admins)
You could do the same but you would have to check the userId and have a player1secretinfo, player2secretinfo etc. (or perhaps a secretinfo array/object but then you would have to only publish one particular index/property)

You could also do a transform in the publications:
https://www.eventedmind.com/items/meteor-transforming-collection-documents

Please post it, if you find a good solution :)